# Configure jacocoTestReport to read multiple .exec files as input

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

In my gradle build I have 2 test tasks like this:

```
task testAAA(type: Test) {
    filter {

        includeTestsMatching "*AAA*"
    }

    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
```

and

```
task testBBB(type: Test) {
    filter {

        includeTestsMatching "*BBB*"
    }

    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
```

This generates 2 .exec files in build/jacoco:

- testAAA.exec
- testBBB.exec

I want to generate a single coverage report that takes input from BOTH/ALL of the .exec files, I tried this:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }

}
```

When I try that I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':Project1:jacocoTestReport'.
> Unable to read execution data file Project1/build/jacoco/test.exec

Project1/build/jacoco/test.exec (No such file or directory)
```

Why is jacocoTestReport looking for "test.exec" when I explicitly provided an executionData specification?

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend passing in the test tasks instead of a file tree. This will allow the plugin to make sure the correct files are looked up *and* will resolve some execution ordering problems that could happen, like making sure this report tasks runs *after* the test tasks themselves.

So something like:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    executionData tasks.withType(Test)

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I struggled with this for a while and even had success. Until I came back to it yesterday. Spent a few hours searching and found this on GH.

```
jacocoTestReport {
  getExecutionData().setFrom(fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec")) 
}
```

As of Gradle 6.0 this is the route to go. Have tested it against a repo that has 2 sets of tests and I can run either separately or both at once and Jacoco doesn't blow up.

[Jacoco JavaDocs](https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/javadoc/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/tasks/JacocoReportBase.html)
[GH Issue with solution](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5898)

Answer (score 2):

The predefined JacocoReport task whose name is `jacocoTestReport` will be set an execution data file by default, whose name is "test.exec".

So, you can try the following code:

```
task testAAAReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    sourceSets sourceSets.main

    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }

}
```

[the source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/cfe5908c9b7aeeaec4912b14471aa4e7448c282d/subprojects/jacoco/src/main/java/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/plugins/JacocoPlugin.java#L179)

Answer (score 1):

build.gradle.kts

```
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    executionData.setFrom(fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec"))
    classDirectories.setFrom(sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree)
    reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
        html.required.set(true)
    }
    finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification)
}

tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    executionData.setFrom(fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec"))
    classDirectories.setFrom(sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).